# Angular 4 - Only show image when src is set

Tags: angular

in my component.html i got `<img [src]="terminalImage" width="15%">` so i want an image to be displayed after the user has used the search function. But now, when he enters the `/search` route, he sees this, till he used the search:

[image]

So i need the image to be hidden or sth. like that, till the user has used the search function and `[src]` is filled.

Comment: ofc - sorry ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Juse use *ngIf

```
<img *ngIf="terminalImage" [src]="terminalImage" width="15%">
```